# Как сделать Dash(рывок) в Construct 2?

Tags: разработка-игр

Делаю свой платформер используя Construct 2, но столкнулся с проблемой что не понимаю как реализовать рывок персонажа. Я пробовал при нажатии клавиши Shift передвигать персонажа на 500 пикселей вперёд, но он просто шёл быстрее(пробовал ставить значение больше но не помогало).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо каким-то очень умным личностям некий дизлайк на посте. Посидев и подумав в общей сумме 6 часов над проблемой, я нашёл способ её решения
[image: рывок]

Мне нужно было изменять не только вектор направления игрока для рывка, но и на пару мили-секунд увеличивать максимальную скорость игрока на n-ое значение, таким образом добавив ещё пару функций я добился солидного рывка.

Рад если кому то помогло это!